# What's going on with aptitude and 49 installed versions ofdocker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt, apt-get, aptitude

It appears I have 49 version of docker CE installed.

```
# aptitude show -v docker-ce | grep -e Version | wc -l
49
```

I'm investigating a docker issue (which I'll post in another question) and I found this. It seems something is malfunctioning. Not sure how to fix it (install only the latest):

```
# aptitude show -v docker-ce | grep -e Version -e State
Version: 5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed
Version: 5:20.10.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:20.10.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:19.03.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:19.03.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Version: 18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu)
Version: 18.06.2~ce~3-0~ubuntu
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (18.06.2~ce~3-0~ubuntu)
Version: 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu)
Version: 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu)
Version: 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
State: installed (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), upgrade available (18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu)
```

Using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

`docker version` shows:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:56 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:40 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

And docker was installed from Docker repository:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

Comment: You have *5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-bionic* installed. Reason: 20.10.17 matches that version

Comment: Aren't the others installed as well?